# bug or syntax error in like sql

Tags: php, mysql

hi i have a bit of a problem on my sql query.. i dont know if my syntax is wrong or if this is a bug.. 
im new on sql and php so i hope there is an answer to this agony XD

im developing a web app for leads on a site.. and i need to add a search funtion.. this is my simple query on my webapp.. the problem is when i search for 4-5 character letter entry it returned 0 results,

```
      SELECT * FROM bought
      INNER JOIN registers ON registers.id = bought.id
      WHERE name LIKE '%".$search."%'
      AND status = 'sold' 
      ORDER BY warranty DESC
```

i tried testing it on php myadmin query using

```
      SELECT * FROM bought
      INNER JOIN registers ON registers.id = bought.id
      WHERE name LIKE '%scott%'
      AND status = 'sold' 
      ORDER BY warranty DESC
```

it returned the correct result. the result is

### name:    status

### Scott O  sold

been figuring this out for hours

my db

```
name :       status

Scott M      open

Scott B      open

scott S      open

Scott O      sold

scott        contacted
```

and the wierdest thing is that all the other search queries outputs are fine.. its just this scott o thing bugs me.

Comment: And somebody is just supposed to guess what your schema is, what you are trying to do and what the results are? Wow these people must be good if you can't figure it out with all that info and they can without it!

Comment: Question isn't clear, Check if $search variable has the data encoded then decode it first before adding it to your query.

Comment: my apologies .. im new in SO

Comment: echo $search right before the query is generated and make sure that it contains the value that you expect...

Comment: the $search echoes the right value.. my problem is the result of my query. if i type 3 letter char on the search, it results "scott o" which is correct..

Comment: @obe but when i type in the full "scott" word  the result is 0

Comment: @bonito I'm not sure I understand... What do you mean by "the full 'scott' word"? Maybe provide the exact and full query that is not returning any results...

Comment: show us on [sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/), because i cant reproduce your problem

Comment: Your collation may be part of the problem. In many collations `LIKE` is case-sensitive, so `LIKE '%scott%'` will match 'scott' but will not match 'Scott' or 'SCOTT'

Comment: ill try to test again.. i did some fiddle here.. new user also .. http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/06dad3/1

Comment: when i type in "sco" on the search .. it output scott o.. but when i type in "scott" on the search.. it outputs nothing.. XD

Comment: works for me http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/06dad3/5

Comment: @dagon thnx alot.. ill apply this later. need to search more on this. how can i upvote?

Comment: I take it the first code is from your PHP: `WHERE name LIKE '%".$search."%'` I would change it to `WHERE name LIKE '%{$search}%'` I don't know why the double quotes are there. Also, out of topic, remember to escape your strings before passing to sql, but maybe you already knew that

Comment: tried your method but still no result. still searching for the answer. no luck till now